# where does eclipse bouncy castle jar come from

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dependencies, bouncycastle

I am compiling an ear file from the Eclipse. I don't have the bcprov-jdk15on-1.51
 .jar declared anywhere in the codebase (neither in pom.xml, nor in Deployment Assembly). But it goes into the lib directory of the ear file. Where was it populated from?

Comment: There is probably a different dependency that you do you use that has bc as a dependency, which, [according to mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/usages), there are quite a few.

Comment: Execute `mvn dependency:tree`, and you'll know

Answer (score 2):

As @MattClark said, it's probably required by one of your dependencies. Open up your pom in eclipse and go to the "Dependency Hierarchy" tab, select the bouncy castle jar from the "Resolved Dependencies" section on the right and eclipse will actually filter the "Dependency Hierarchy" view to show you exactly why that jar is being included.

Comment: Good to hear @rickcoup, please remember to mark the answer as the chosen answer.